# Why i get must use a @JoinColumn instead of @Column

Tags: java, persistence

i am tryning to join two entities where  typDossAmo can have a list of DossMedic
but i get the following error:
Entity class [class ma.cnss.wstest.TypDossAmo] must use a @JoinColumn instead of @Column to map its relationship attribute [drugs].

```
public class TypDossAmo implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private BigInteger id;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 9)
    @Column(name = "NUM_DOSS")
    private String numDoss;
   
    @Column(name = "p_tab_medic")
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="doss")
    private List<DossMedic> drugs;........
```

```
public class DossMedic implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @EmbeddedId
    protected DossMedicPK dossMedicPK;
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private BigInteger id;
    @Column(name = "NOMBRE")
    private BigInteger nombre;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="NUM_DOSS")
    private TypDossAmo doss;
```

Answer (score 1):

The idea of the annotation **@Column** is for common columns without any relationship with other tables, when you use **@JoinColumn** is to say to the ORM that two tables have a relationship and the way to join them is with this column.
In this case the solution is change the annotation **@Column** by **@JoinColumn** in **TypDossAmo**

```
public class TypDossAmo {

    @JoinColumn(name = "p_tab_medic")
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="doss")
    private List<DossMedic> drugs;
}
```

Comment: So where is exactly the problem?

Comment: I think the solution could be:

public class TypDossAmo {
......
    @JoinColumn(name = "p_tab_medic")
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="doss")
    private List<DossMedic> drugs;........